# session_start() blocks page load

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with the function `session_start();` as it blocks file execution (i.e page loads forever) to even after PHP Max execution time, i thought it was a problem with my code however i cleared all my files and just used this simple script to test and it didn't work

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['name'] = "foo";
 $name = $_SESSION['name'];
 echo "My name is $name";
```

I'm using WAMP server version 3.0.6 64bit, Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: What happens if you just `echo "hello world";` instead of your echo?

Comment: it doesn't even show errors as page is still loading

Comment: @AndyHolmes it runs normally

Comment: So what happens if you do `echo 'My name is '.$name;` ?

Comment: @AndyHolmes , the problem is not with the `echo` , even if i use `echo $name;` it doesn't work

Comment: But you just said the other echo worked normally?

Comment: are you using xamp?

Comment: try this:-`<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 $_SESSION['name'] = "foo";
 echo "My name is ".$_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: yes `echo` works normally if i remove `session_start()` and just write `echo "hello world!";` @Andy

Comment: Lol yeah I said *"instead of your echo"* of course it will work if you remove the session that's what we were checking . Glad you got it sorted though

Comment: @AndyHolmes Sorry i didn't get it because it blocked all code , so i knew it wouldn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using file sessions you will need to close writing to the session to prevent multiple PHP requests (that need $_SESSION data) from blocking.
example:

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();
// I can read/write to session
$_SESSION['latestRequestTime'] = time();
// close the session
session_write_close();
// now do my long-running code.
```

[more about the solution](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/)

Comment: Thank you bro, However I'm using cookie sessions , is that still applicable ?

Comment: yes.
cookie session is how you tell the server that this client is connected to that session, in all cases, the data is still stored in the server files.

Comment: Well i tried, it didn't work , however the topic is right as i had to add `session_start([
    'read_and_close' => true
]);` to prevent blocking (just like you said)

Comment: @a4w - Honestly, this is mind-blowing, that session_start() is causing such a blockage! Thanks for the solution.